# How to assign two actions on the same key press in Java?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a JavaFX application and I wanna assign some actions on key press.
I have the keyCode SHIFT assigned to action that make opacity of AnchorPane as 1.0 and I have the KeyCode SLASH assigned to action that set the same AnchorPane opacity to 0.0.

I wanna refactor key presses and set all actions on one keyCode DEAD_TILDE.

I wanna make a key press on a keyboard act as toggle key press. When I press DEAD_TILDE key opacity of AnchorPane should be set as 1.0 if I press same DEAD_TILDE again opacity of AnchorPane should be set as 0.0

**How Can I do that?**

I've tried to create a boolean and use it in a method. But id doesn't work or I just did it in a wrong way:

```
@FXML  private AnchorPane mainAnchor, previewCard;

private boolean opacityCard = false;

@FXML
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

  showCardPreview();
}

private void showCardPreview() {

mainAnchor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
  if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DEAD_TILDE || !opacityCard) {
    opacityCard = false;
    previewCard.setOpacity(1.0);

    } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DEAD_TILDE || true) {
    opacityCard = true;
    previewCard.setOpacity(0.0);
     }
  });
 }
```

That is how I assigned two keyCodes on two actions:

```
 @FXML  private AnchorPane mainAnchor, previewCard;

 //key commands
  mainAnchor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    switch (event.getCode()) {          

      case SHIFT:
        previewCard.setOpacity(1.0);
        break;

      case SLASH:
        previewCard.setOpacity(0.0);
        break;      
    }
  });
 }
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried to use this one, but nothing happens:

```
  @FXML
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

mainAnchor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
  if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DEAD_TILDE) {
    previewCard.setOpacity(previewCard.getOpacity() == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0);
    event.consume();
    }
  });

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I've discovered that I have EventFilter in my code, so I've just refactored it like this, and this wroked! I also changed keyCode to DIGIT4 because DEAD_TILDA sign doesn't work

```
 //assign keys to some events
  mainAnchor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
      event.consume();
      flipCard();
    } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DIGIT4) {
      event.consume();
      previewCard.setOpacity(previewCard.getOpacity() == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the handler, toggle the state based on the current state. In other words, if the opacity is at `1.0` change it to `0.0` and vice versa.

```
mainAnchor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DEAD_TILDE) {
        previewCard.setOpacity(previewCard.getOpacity() == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0);
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

As you're toggling between `0.0` and `1.0` you may want to consider using the `visible` property instead.

```
mainAnchor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DEAD_TILDE) {
        previewCard.setVisible(!previewCard.isVisible());
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried to put one of your code in Initialize method, but none of them doesn't work

Comment: If this isn't working then the problem is likely somewhere else in your code. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve]. Are you sure you're even getting pressed events for `DEAD_TILDE`?

Comment: when I tried to use your code with opacity for a AnchorPane I also had switch operator(see a code in the topic) and this code of switch operator for pressing SHIFT and SLASH worked perfectly fine, but your code didn't react when I press DEAD_TILDA at the this time. I also tried to use another keyCodes like DIGIT4, same situation. I don't understand what I did wrong. Should I place your code in some method and use it in Initialize method?

Comment: Make sure `mainAnchor` or a descendant has the focus; otherwise key events won't be sent to it. You could try calling `mainAnchor.requestFocus()`. Note that requires it be part of a `Scene` to work.

Comment: I've found the solution,please check my edit! but my TILDA sign doesn't work, instead of this I used another keyCode like DIGIT 4, do you have any thougths why TILDA sign doesn't work? If I open notepad tild sign works perfectly, so my keyboard works correctly

Comment: I don't know and I can't test it because I don't have that key on my keyboard (afaik). Just to make sure, you do want `DEAD_TILDE` correct? Not just the tilde key (`~`)? 'Cause on my keyboard the `~` is on the "back quote" key (i.e. `KeyCode.BACK_QUOTE`).

Comment: Yes! you are totally right! It is BACK_QUOTE:D I didn't know that:) Thank you very much for the answer!